# Cocoapods does not update single pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I want to update `Parse` SDK. So I run `pod update 'Parse'` in terminal. And it has no effect. Parse version remains 1.8.5. It is only when I run `pod update` then `Parse` version becomes the latest 1.14.2. However it also updates the rest of the pods, which is not what I need. Did anybody ever encounter that? This is my podfile:

```
platform :ios, '8.0'

target 'MIPA' do

pod "AKPickerView"
pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', '~> 2.2'
pod 'Parse'
pod "HockeySDK"
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'AFNetworkActivityLogger'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'FontAwesomeKit', '~> 2.1.0'
pod 'Optimizely-iOS-SDK'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'Intercom'
pod 'Mixpanel'
pod 'CTAssetsPickerController'
pod 'MGSwipeTableCell'
pod 'NSOperationQueue+CompletionBlock', '~> 1.0'
pod 'BEMSimpleLineGraph'
pod 'DACircularProgress'
pod 'BugfenderSDK'
pod 'FastttCamera'
pod 'Masonry'
pod 'ActionSheetPicker-3.0', '~> 2.0.4'
pod 'apptentive-ios'
pod 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'

end

target 'MIPATests' do

pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'SSKeychain'

end

target 'MIPAUITests' do

pod 'FontAwesomeKit', '~> 2.1.0'
pod 'MagicalRecord/Shorthand', '~> 2.2'
pod "AFNetworking", "~> 2.0"
pod 'SSKeychain'

end
```

Comment: Can you try commenting it out (`#pod 'Parse'`) and run `pod install`, then un-comment it out and re run `pod install`? Not a solution tho.

Comment: this is the most amazing thing. Parse does not get removed when I uncomment it and run pod install

Comment: It may be a dependency issue?

Comment: you mean it is Parse fault? I'll try to figure out

Comment: No i mean that some other app may specify it needs Parse pod as a dependency, ParseFacebookUtilsV4 for example, so that it keeps it anyway, but i am not sure.

Comment: well, I do use ParseFacebookUtilsV4. I think this should be the case. Then how am I supposed to handle it? Is there a way to update just a couple of pods?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127395/discussion-between-jalone-and-andrey-chernukha).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some other app may specify it needs Parse pod as a dependency, ParseFacebookUtilsV4 for example, so that it keeps it anyway even when removing it or trying to update.

You can #comment out both Parse and the other pods whose relate to it, this may require to go by attempt, run install, then uncomment them and run pod install again

Comment: Here is the answer from the chat :)

Answer (score 0):

In installing pods, sometimes it happens that you don't get some dependencies updated. They get to the best compatible version required by your app. If you want to update only Parse, you can use `pod 'Parse'~>1.14.2` instead of `pod 'Parse'`. This might solve your problem.